# How to use Split or explode Function in Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

Observer File :

```
<?php
  class Gta_MatchProductOrder_Model_Observer
  {
    public function checkproductinorder($Observer)
    {
      $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $items = $order->getAllItems();
      $skus = array(
                    '654568',
                    '600_1',
                    '757657685',
                    '65786785'); //product SKUs

      $skuList = array();
      foreach ($items as $item)
      {
        if(in_array($item->getSku(), $skus))
        {
          $orderid = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
          $skuList[] = $item->getSku();
        }
      }
      Mage::log('The order Id ' . $orderid . ' contains amazon list SKU : '.implode(',',$skuList), null, 'matchorder.log');

      ### start test observer ###
      // $order = $Observer->getEvent();
      // Mage::log($order->getName(),null,'orderproduct.log');
      ### end test observer ###
    }
  }
?>
```

From above code how to use split or explode function for my `sku's`. 
my sku combination : 654568, 757657685, 65786785, 600_1.

fyi = sku 654568, 757657685, 65786785  have 654568_01, 654568_02 & 654568_01, 654568_02 & 65786785_1, 65786785_2   here underscore is unique.

As of now if order contains the product 600_1 return log message, if order contains  654568_01 how can i print in log?

Comment: this should give you the result your after without exploding if(strpos($item->getSku(), '600_') !== false) {

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is the way, Here you have to just take $item->getSku() in on Variable and then you need to split it, For Ex:

```
public function checkproductinorder($Observer)

{

$order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) 

{

  $splitSKU = explode('_',$item->getSku()); 

  if($splitSKU[0] == '600')

    {

      Mage::log('yes, the selected product available in order', null, 'matchorder.log');

    }

}
```

If you use this code spinnet then you can easily get answer.

Comment: If more than one sku, what i need to do, like, 223344_01, 3456_01, 75657_04, 7456756_06, here underscore unique.

Comment: You need to check first SKU contains _ or not, Then in True 2nd Condition you need to check once string get _ Break that string in 2 parts.Then it works for multiple SKU without any problem

Comment: could you pls explain in brief?

Comment: As my post sku 654568, if order contains 654568_01, i need to trigger?

Comment: One thing, You just change your if condition as if (strpos($splitSKU[0], '_') == false) {

Comment: if i update  if (strpos($splitSKU[0], '_') == false), what about my  if(in_array($item->getSku(), $skus)) condition?

Comment: add one more if condition (if (strpos($splitSKU[0], '_') == false)) in your ( if(in_array($item->getSku(), $skus))) if condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98807/discussion-between-zus-and-oscprofessionals).

Answer (score 1):

You can split your sku by following code and get result.

```
public function checkproductinorder($Observer)
{
    $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
        list($underscore_before, $underscore_after) = explode('_', $item->getSku());

        if($underscore_before == '600')
        {
          Mage::log('yes, the slecetd product available in order', null, 'matchorder.log');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If more than one sku, what i need to do, like, 223344_01, 3456_01, 75657_04, 7456756_06, here underscore unique.

Comment: Hello @Khushbu Mehta, how to print foreach key values in mage::log code : https://justpaste.it/6nc8d

Answer (score 1):

instead of `if($item->getSku() == '600')` you can try

```
$prefix = '600_';
if (substr($item->getSku(), 0, strlen($prefix)) === $prefix) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function checkproductinorder($Observer)

 {

  $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  $items = $order->getAllItems();
  foreach ($items as $item) 

  {

    $SKU = explode('_',$item->getSku()); 

    if($SKU[0] == '600'){
      Mage::log('the selected product available in order SKU start with '.$SKU[0], null, 'matchorder.log');
    }


}
```